# Anonymize Excel cell contents

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is there a way (without VBA) to change the content of a cell in Excel so that nobody can see a client name?  So for example in a list of cells I may have:

Smith
Jones
Williams
etc...

I want to set up the cell so that when the inputter types in the client name, they can see it to make sure it's correct but on pressing return or moving away from the cell it then anonymizes it so it looks like this:

**ith
**nes
*****ams

Or something similar.  Once anonymized the original name cannot be viewed.

Thanks

Comment: A way to do this without VBA? No.

Comment: Whatever way you decide to accomplish this - keep in mind it will take a few seconds to break it for anyone with a little knowledge of Excel.  Will probably take even less time for someone with no knowledge to accidentally break it.  Having said that - you could give it a custom number format of `;;;**` - any entered text will appear as `********` after you press Enter (but the real text will still appear in the formula bar).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Without VBA**:

```
=CONCATENATE(REPT("*",(LEN(A1)-LEN(A1)/2+MOD(LEN(A1),2))),
             RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)/2+MOD(LEN(A1),2)))
```

It concatenates two parts:

- half of the length is presented as `*` through the `REPT` function
- the second half of the length is left. The `MOD(LEN(A1),2)` part is needed to support even and odd length of the strings.

**With VBA**

Judging from your question, you need something like a login form. The best way to do it is:

- make `UserForm` (with VBA);
- add a `TextBox`;
- in the properties of the `TextBoxc` set the `PasswordChar` to `*` or anything else;

[image]

Comment: Great, thanks very much, the non-VBA version works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Copy all of your names to another sheet, then remove duplicates. 
On the de-duped list, put a code or fake name (Adam Zapple, Barb Dwyer etc.) next to each original name. Then use VLOOKUP on your original data to pull through each code/fake name. Copy and paste the VLookup column as a value then delete the original name column.

Comment: The issue here is that I need the anonymizing to happen as soon as they enter the name.